# How to delay parsing these required variables before the data has loaded?

Tags: ios, swift, google-places-api

I'm retrieving lat and long coordinates from the google places api that are used to display information in a tableView. The tableView results are based off these coordinates. I am parsing the coordinates over to the tableView in the function below, however the TableViewController is being pushed before the coordinated are retrieved. How can I delay the push until the coordinate data has come through? Thanks.

```
func placeSelected(place: Place) {
    println(place.description)

    var lat = 0.0
    var lng = 0.0

    place.getDetails { details in

        lat = details.latitude   // Convenience accessor for latitude
        lng = details.longitude  // Convenience accessor for longitude
    }

    let locationData = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TableViewController") as TableViewController

    locationData.searchLat = lat
    locationData.searchLng = lng

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(locationData, animated: true)

}
```

Comment: You could try putting the `locationData` vc instantiation inside of the `place.getDetails` callback. Then to make sure you update your ui on the main thread you can use gcd's `dispatch_sync` on `dispatch_get_main_queue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could instantiate and push your TableViewController from the completion closure of the getDetails method.

```
func placeSelected(place: Place) {
    println(place.description)

    place.getDetails { [weak self] details in
        let lat = details.latitude   // Convenience accessor for latitude
        let lng = details.longitude  // Convenience accessor for longitude

        if let self = self, locationData = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TableViewController") as? TableViewController {
            locationData.searchLat = lat
            locationData.searchLng = lng

            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(locationData, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

This assumes that the closure is called on the main thread.

You probably want to show some kind of activity indicator while the getDetails method is running.